# Shopware6.5 App How to get Form Post Request or set Variable for a Twig Scripts (Cart script hook)?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I have a script in scripts/cart (cart script hook) which is always called when calculating the shopping cart.

But there is a method in there that always also deletes the items of a shopping cart.

But now I want to change this by having it empty the cart only when the user has clicked on a link or a button.

How do I implement this? How can I, for example, via a form post or a variable that is set when clicking, query this in the script and only then perform the deletion?

I have tried with Form Post, I do not get an app.request at this point (in the cart script hook).

The checkout/offcanvas-cart.html.twig script is creating the text-link for example, where I could include a form.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the possibility of this.

The hook for cart scripts is dispatched on every request. Unfortunately the hook does not provide the request data. If the request data would be available in the script, you could request any storefront URL with a certain query parameter, and depending on its existence clear the cart within the cart hook script.

There's also the [`storefront-{hook}`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference#storefront-hook) which does provide the request data, but not the cart service. And furthermore that hook is dispatched after the cart hook, so you also can't use the request data in one script and pass along data to another script, say as an added state to the `Context`.

So, as of today, unfortunately, I don't think this is possible with just app scripts.

I did some quick testing and adding `RequestFacadeFactory::class` to the [array returned by `CartHook::getServiceIds`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Checkout/Cart/Hook/CartHook.php#L45) did work and made `services.request` become available and then allowed me to do something like this in the cart hook script:

```
{% if services.request.query.foo === 'bar' %}
    {# clear the cart #}
{% endif %}
```

So you could then link to any valid URL of the shop with the query string `?foo=bar` and it would clear the cart. However there's probably a good reason, why `CartHook` might not provide the request facade, as it could be that this hook is also dispatched in the context of console commands, where there is no request at all. If you feel like contributing, you could create a pull request with this one small change to see where it leads.

Comment: Thank you. Let's find another solution for this.

How can I create a Javascript request to delete items in the cart, when clicking on the link or form button?

Perform a DELETE request to the /checkout/cart/line-item endpoint to remove line items from the cart.
[code]
    // DELETE /store-api/checkout/cart/line-item
    
    {
        "ids": [
            "<id>"
        ]
    }
[/code]

Comment: Another idea maybe, the cart script hook cannot accept cookie information? So Javascript could write something to a cookie when the button or link clicked and on page reload the hook could access the info? But I guess that is not possible?

Comment: Created a pull request https://github.com/shopware/platform/pull/3263